# TypeError during using python dataclass

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

```
@dataclass
class cntr(setup):
    source:str = 'S2'
    vi:str = 'SW'
    # Dataframe containing information on samples
    df:pd.DataFrame = pd.DataFrame()

    # Available bands
    bands:List[str] = field(default_factory=[])

    indices:List[str] = [vi] + bands
```

In the code above, I get this error for the line `indices:List[str] = [vi] + bands`:

`*** TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "Field") to list`

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define `indices` in `__post_init__`. It will not appear in the `repr` but it will be accessible as a property.

You also need to have a callable for `default_factory`, so `list` instead of `[]` .

Here is a simplified example (as I do not know what is `setup`:

```
@dataclass
class cntr():
    source:str = 'S2'
    vi:str = 'SW'
    # Available bands
    bands:List[str] = field(default_factory=list)

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.indices:List[str] = [self.vi] + self.bands
c = cntr()
c.indices  # will print: ['SW']
```